# Pascal sintax error, ";" expected but "ELSE" found

Tags: pascal, freepascal

i'm new programming, so be kind...
i compile and got the error mentioned in the title, the code goes

```
while n>1 do
    if n mod p= 0   then
            write(p);
            n:= n div p;
            else p:= p+1
    end
end.
```

i'd like to know what's bad with that `'else'`

Comment: except for indenting problems (which do not matter), there is nothing wrong with your else. But you need a ``;`` in the line above it. So do you need one after ``p:=p+1;``

Comment: after ends also you need to put semicolon, after each line of code except begin and procedures header, you need to put a semicolon

Comment: Because you forgot to put a semicolon after n:= n div p, the compiler didn't realize the line ended. So it just kept going, hit the else, and got confused that it hit an "else" rather than a ";", because "else" wouldn't be valid syntax at the end of the line. That's what it's trying to tell you.

Comment: i put the semicolon after n:=n div p and still giving me the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to add "begin-end" after "then"
you need to do it in case you have more than one instruction.

```
while n>1 do
    if n mod p= 0   then
       Begin
            write(p);
            n:= n div p;
       End else p:= p+1
    end
end.
```

Comment: thanks, that fixed my problem